# In AWS flow framework, Can we have same activity implementation being used by 2 different workflows

Tags: amazon-web-services, workflow, amazon-swf

We have a requirement where we have 2 separate workflows but there are few common activities between them. We want to save the effort of replicating the code in 2 places and maintain it separately for such activities. Is it possible for 2 workflows to share same activity implementation. Does AWS flow framework support that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SWF as well as AWS Flow framework treats workflows and activities completely independently. So activities don't belong to any particular workflow. They can be invoked by any workflow. Think about them as services that can be called by anyone assuming correct permissions.

So your workflows absolutely can share activities.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Maxim. Can you share any cons that you can see with this approach?

Comment: I don't think there are cons as it is by design. BTW check out my latest project temporal.io which is a greatly improved open source version of SWF.